# How can I get the images from the subdirectory just created and assigned to the dropdown list in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/Images/") + txtFolder.Text
```

After I create new folder with some images, How can I retreive them and assign to a ddlist
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to get list of files in directory that you have created and also bind dropdown list.

```
string DirecotryPath = Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/Images/") + txtFolder.Text);
            if (Directory.Exists(DirecotryPath))
            {
                string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(DirecotryPath);
                int counter = 1;
                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    string filename = file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf("\\"), file.Length);
                    ListItem li = new ListItem(counter.ToString(), counter.ToString());
                    li.Attributes.Add("data-image", "~/images/" + filename);
                    ddlList.Items.Add(li);
                }
            }
```

Comment: you can check from this url http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/33b051/binding-image-indropdownlist-in-asp-dotnet/ I have miss javascript side code so you can get full details from above link